# Trying to access int from a struct pointer: compiles but does not run

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to access an `int` from the `struct` pointer `pPoint`. The following code compiles, but when the program is run at the command prompt, my computer says the program has stopped working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct point *pPoint;

struct point {
    int num;
    pPoint pt2; 
} pt1;

int main() {
    pt1.num = 9;
    pt1.pt2->num = 7;
    printf("%d ", pt1.num);
    printf("%d\n", pt1.pt2->num);
    return 0;
}
```

Where is the error and what needs to be changed?

Comment: The debugger is your friend, and would probably have shown you your error.

Answer (score 3):

You have not allocated any memory for what the `pt2` pointer points to. Therefore when you perform

```
pt1.pt2->num = 7;
```

you are writing a value to what is on the end of an uninitialised pointer. This is undefined behaviour. You need to make sure that `pt2` points to a valid `point` struct before you try assigning values to the variables within it,

Answer (score 0):

you should allocate memory for it like this:

```
int main() {
pt1.num = 9;
pPoint new = (struct point *)malloc(sizeof(struct point));
pt1.pt2 = new;
pt1.pt2->num = 7;
printf("%d ", pt1.num);
printf("%d\n", pt1.pt2->num);
return 0;
}
```